# Change apps directory?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have recently installed ubuntu linux 14.04 on my system (Its a dual boot with windows 8.1). Everything went good. But, now when I installed some apps (google chrome for example), the app is getting installed in usr/lib directory.

Now the problem : I remember while installing ubuntu, I partitioned the free space into 3 : root, home and swap. Sizes are as follows: Root:17-18 GB; Home: 80GB; Swap-8GB

I want all the apps to be installed in /home directory. Is it possible? 
The free space available in usr/lib directory is around 12GB, which I don't feel is enough for me. 
Is it possible to change to /home directory?

P.S I'm completely new to ubuntu and this is the first time I'm using linux.

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

> I want all the apps to be installed in /home directory. Is it possible?

Yes. But you need to install software from SOURCE not from the software center. Before you start thinking about doing that please keep reading.

> The free space available in usr/lib directory is around 12GB, which I don't feel is enough for me. Is it possible to change to /home directory?

Beside leaving the installation method Ubuntu uses by default... there are other options ...

If you do not use hibernate and have a largish amount of money you can free up space by deleting swap. You can also resize /home and "/" by moving a bit from /home/ to "/". You can make a separate partition of /usr/ or /var/ by splitting /home/ into 2 partitions and mounting that other directory in the empty one.
And the is not even mentioning the more simple option of adding a extra hard disk to a desktop.

The question you need to answer: if you have a 17Gb "/" and you now have still 12 Gb free  ... *What* are you planning to install to fill up that 12Gb?! And if you can answer that: you believe you need ALL those 12Gb worth of software at the same time?

My personal partitoning:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        99G  7,2G   87G   8% /
/dev/sdb5        25G  2,2G   22G  10% /home
/dev/sdb6       365G  174G  173G  51% /discworld
```

I have 2 disks in my notebook (the 99G one is an SSD). And I have MySQL running on this machine (as with all personal data: the SQL database file is on /discworld/). I have never ever been over 10Gb Used the whole time using Ubuntu. And my /home/ never ever got over 3Gb Used.

No you'll be fine with your current setup. I would start to worry when your "/" is filled up 90+%. Not sooner.